# Core Plot: Setting different colours for each bar in bar graph

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am trying to plot bar graph in positive and negative direction,Just wanted to know if I can give one colour to bar plot in positve direction and another colour to bar plot in negative direction?Currently all my bars are in one colour.How do i change all bars in positive to red colour and all bars in negative to blue colour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the `-barFillForBarPlot:recordIndex:` datasource method. For each index, check the data value associated with the given index and return the desired fill.

Answer (score 1):

you just should do something like this:

```
-(CPTFill *)barFillForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx {

    return [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:147./255. green:200./255. blue:1. alpha:0.5]];
}
```